# how time complexity of sorted array in bubble sort is o(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I have doubt regarding time complexity of bubble sort. in bubble sort they told that for sorted array it takes o(n) but i checked the bubble sort with "count" variable in sorted array.the loop is taking time same as the unsorted array. so why they put for sorted array time complexity is o(n).

Comment: for sorted array it is O(n) because it stops if no swaps were performed. not sure which unsorted array you were testing but it definitely can't run in O(n). what did you count in `count` variable?

Comment: There are different ways to code bubble sort of which some might end up as O(n^2) even in sorted array cases. look here to check how O(n) bubbloe sort on sorted array is possible https://www.programiz.com/dsa/bubble-sort

Comment: very thanks to show me the optimized bubble sort.